# Write a specific number of decimal places of a pandas series to text file

Tags: python, text, series

[image: The]I am writing a pandas time series to text file so that I can use it in another program.  The problem is that when there are zeros at the end of values in the time series, the number of decimal places is reduced.  I want to write to 8 decimal places even when there are trailing zeros because if the number of decimal places is not consistent the other program wont read the text file.

I tried using decimal but I don't the values written as a string.

This is how I am writing the series shown below to text:

```
smp_simpath = 
os.path.join(path,'forward_simulated_heads_extensive_25.smp')
smp_simfile = open(smp_simpath, "w") 
datetime_format="%d/%m/%Y    %H:%M:%S"
# MW
for i in range(0, len(simulated_time_series['MW1'])): 
    smp_simfile.write(
            'MW1'+ "    " + 
      str(simulated_time_series['MW1'].index[i].strftime(datetime_format)) 
      + "    
      " + str(
        simulated_time_series['MW1'].values[i]) + "\n")
```

The text file output is shown below, and a few of the values in the last column have different decimal points.[image]

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the current input and the expected output?

Comment: Did you try f-strings with format specification? Something like this: ```value=84.0``` and then ```print(f'{value:5.9f}')``` resulting in ```84.000000000```.

Comment: If you are still on Python 2, check the [old string formatting method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting)

Comment: Thanks that helps, yes I am still on python 2.

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/Tracebacks.  Just copy the text, paste it in your question and format it as code.
[You should not post code as an image because:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755) ... [Formatting posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)